How do use netmiko to send a tab-complete command and read the output?
I'm new to netmiko (and network automation in general tbh), and I'm currently trying to use it to send a command that, when used manually, requires you to press tab a few times in order to get the full result (two tabs for output to appear, another to view the rest, pressing enter will give you a syntax error). So far, I haven't been able to make this work programmatically.
The first method I tried looked like this:
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

def send_commands_tab(self, command):
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**self.device)
    net_connect.read_channel()
    time.sleep(1)
    net_connect.write_channel(command + '\t')
    time.sleep(1)
    return net_connect.read_channel()

This just returns the command itself with a tab's worth of whitespace (or more, if I add more \t). Adding a newline triggers the syntax error.
I also tried
def send_commands_tab(self, command):
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**self.device)
        net_connect.read_channel()
        time.sleep(1)
        
        net_connect.send_command(command + '\t\t\t', normalize=False)
        time.sleep(1)
        return net_connect.read_channel()

This just returns user@machine, which is even more confusing, and nothing at all if I add a newline.
I've tried some other minor variations with no luck printing anything resembling my desired result.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Netmiko's doc doesn't help much regarding what you have to put into command; you might need a \n at the end?

Solution - this was a netmiko version issue. downgrading netmiko to ver 3.3.2 from 4.8.0 (pip3 install netmiko==3.3.2) fixed the problem.
